# How to transform multiple column into successive line in awk

Tags: awk

I have a file A.txt (sep = `\t` , first column is empty):

```
    Cycle  A1  A2  B1
    1      4   5   2
    2      7   3   4
    3      3   2   5
```

And I want to transform this file into a new file B.txt (sep = `\t`) :

```
Well  Cycle  Value
A1     1     4
A1     2     7
A1     3     3
A2     1     5
A2     2     3
A2     3     2
B1     1     2
B1     2     4
B1     3     5
```

I tried something with: `awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}'`
but I couldn't figure it out.
Anyone has a clue how to do this?
Thanks

Comment: I assume the whitespace you had at the beginning of each line was just an artifact of pasting here, so I removed it. Please let me know or put it back if I was wrong and it is part of your file.

Comment: Yep, as mention first column of the file is empty in the raw file

Comment: Is the final output required to be grouped by the first column, as in the example you are showing? (I.e. all the lines for `A1` first, then all those for `A2`, ...).

Comment: @fra-san No it's not required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not `awk`, but using [Miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/index.html), given

```
$ cat file
    Cycle  A1  A2  B1
    1      4   5   2
    2      7   3   4
    3      3   2   5
```

then

```
$ mlr --pprint --ifs tab reshape -i A1,A2,B1 -o Well,Value then sort -f Well then reorder -f Well file
Well Cycle Value
A1   1     4
A1   2     7
A1   3     3
A2   1     5
A2   2     3
A2   3     2
B1   1     2
B1   2     4
B1   3     5
```

You may omit the `sort` step if it's not a requirement.

The Miller `reshape` command can also accept a regular expression for field selection ex.

```
reshape -r '[A-Z][1-9]' -o Well,Value
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I try to have a awk command that are not "hard-coded". I write a test data for this topic , the actual file contain more line and more column

Comment: @nstatam the Miller `reshape` command can also accept a regular expression for field selection - see edit

Comment: I try your example and I have the same file as output. I'm trying to know why

Comment: @nstatam apologies I missed your edit mentioning that your file is tab separated - you will need to add `--ifs tab` (or `--fs tab` if you want tab separated output as well)

Comment: Even with --fs tab I have the same output as the input

Comment: @nstatam OK in that case I can't help you - good luck

Comment: Ok so it seems to have an issue with the "sort part". It works when I olny do the first part. thanks

Comment: is it normal that I have several "^I" between two data ? It seems that the software try to align the data visually ... what is the parameter do prevent that in miller ? thanks

Comment: @nstatam `^I` is the visualization of a tab character, try `printf '\t\n' | cat -T` to see what I mean. Whatever you're using to see the output is displaying tabs as `^I`s.

Comment: @nstatam so it seems that with `--fs tab` Miller adds multiple tabs where a only single tab is required. Perhaps my command is incorrect, or perhaps that is a bug in Miller. As a workaround, you could either use `--ifs tab` and post-process your data to convert space delimiters to tabs, or use `--fs tab` and post process to squeeze multiple tabs to one.

Answer (score 1):

We first load the file in an array of array `AoA[colidx, rowidx]` 
Then in the end of file block we restructure this data in a format we desire.

Note:

- field separator is `\t+` to walk over consecutive tabs and not be handed empty fields.
- the `gsub()` portion is to remove the leading n trailing tabs.
- This code will take care of as many cols and rows as the file has.(memory permitting)

```
awk -F '\t+' '
gsub(/^\t|\t$/, "") {$1=$1}
NR==1 {header = "Well" OFS $1 OFS "Value"}
{
  for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
    AoA[i, NR] = $(i)
  }
}
END {
  print header
  for(col=2; col<=NF; col++) {
    for(row=2; row<=NR; row++) {
      well  = AoA[col, 1]
      cycle = AoA[1, row]
      value = AoA[col, row]
      print well, cycle, value
    }
  }
}
' OFS='\t' -  | column -t
```

**Results:**

```
Well  Cycle  Value
A1    1      4
A1    2      7
A1    3      3
A2    1      5
A2    2      3
A2    3      2
B1    1      2
B1    2      4
B1    3      5
```

Comment: nitpick - `AoA[colidx, rowidx]` isn't an array of arrays, it's a pseudo-multi-dimensional array (i.e. a one-dimensional array using a separator `SUBSEP` between the component parts of its index). An array of arrays would be `AoA[colidx][rowidx]` but  that's only supported by gawk AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one (rather crude) approach that requires the headers to be static and known in advance, and which doesn't sort by well:

```
$ awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" 'BEGIN{print "Well","Cycle","Value"}
                         NR>1{
                            cycle[NR]=$2;
                            a1[NR]=$3; 
                            a2[NR]=$4; 
                            b1[NR]=$5;
                        }
                        END{
                            for(line in cycle){
                                print "A1",cycle[line],a1[line]; 
                                print "A2",cycle[line],a2[line]; 
                                print "B1",cycle[line],b1[line]
                            }
                        }' file 
Well    Cycle   Value
A1  1   4
A2  1   5
B1  1   2
A1  2   7
A2  2   3
B1  2   4
A1  3   3
A2  3   2
B1  3   5
```

If you need to sort by well, you can use the even more crude:

```
$ awk -F'\t' -vOFS="\t" 'BEGIN{print "Well","Cycle","Value"}
                         NR>1{
                            cycle[NR]=$2;
                            a1[NR]=$3; 
                            a2[NR]=$4; 
                            b1[NR]=$5;
                        }
                        END{
                            for(line in cycle){
                                print "A1",cycle[line],a1[line];
                            }
                            for(line in cycle){
                                print "A2",cycle[line],a2[line]; 
                            }
                            for(line in cycle){
                                print "B1",cycle[line],b1[line]
                            }
                        }' file 
Well    Cycle   Value
A1  1   4
A1  2   7
A1  3   3
A2  1   5
A2  2   3
A2  3   2
B1  1   2
B1  2   4
B1  3   5
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I try to have a awk command that are not "hard-coded". I write a test data for this topic , the actual file contain more line and more column